# Running crawler4j on multiple computers | different instances | Root Folder Lock

Tags: java, crawler4j

I'm trying to implement a crawler by using [crawler4j](http://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/). It's running fine until:

1. I Run only 1 copy of it.
2. I run it continuously without restart.

If i restart the crawler, the url's collected are not unique. It is because, the crawler locks the root folder (that stores the intermediate crawler data & passed as an argument). **When crawler restarts, it deletes the content of root data folder.**

Is it possible to:  ?

1. Prevent root data folder from locking. (So, i can run multiple copies of crawler at once.)
2. Content of root data folder does not delete after restart. (So that i can resume the crawler after stop.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to alter the configuration of the crawler using:

```
crawlConfig.setResumableCrawling(true);
```

in `controller.java` class.

And you can follow [this link](https://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/wiki/Configurations) and see Resumable crawling.